# Why is my site loading so slowly, and how to 'minimize request size'?

Tags: html, webserver

I just found out that I should expect my site to get a bunch of traffic today. Great! But it's loading incredibly slowly!

According to Pingdom, the most important fix would be to minimize my request size

http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/jT4ro/radionowhere.net

What does this mean and how do I start fixing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with BlackHat. Minify CSS, Javascript.

And a free CDN you could use is CloudFlare cloudflare.com

You can also make sure you are caching static items (images/javascript/etc).

Another great tool here too... https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Answer (score 1):

To minimize, you basically make your `CSS` and `Javascript` files smaller. You can use tools like [CSS Minifier](http://cssminifier.com/) for your `CSS` and [jscompress](http://jscompress.com/) for `Javascript`.

Another things you can do to help is to use a CDN or content distribution network. This works kind of a like a generic cache, which can help expedite the load time.